# How to reduce delay of "Onload"?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm current using a javascript with the this tag

```
<body onload="javascript:Mine();">
```

Now i noticed that it is taking some time to load this function after i open the page.So is there any other way i can reduce this delay ?

Thanks

Comment: The `javascript:Mine();` syntax is incorrect; better to use simply `Mine();`. `javascript:` is a URI protocol that you would use in links (like `<a href="javascript:Mine();">`), not in event handlers like `onload`.

Comment: In this context it is a (pointless) label: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onload` fires when a page is completely loaded. To get things to fire sooner you can either:

- Make the page load faster

  - Remove, reduce and optimize images (and other content, third party adverts are often a major performance kicker)
  - Follow performance guidelines (such as [those from Yahoo!](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).)
- Not use `onload`

  - Use a library (such as YUI or jQuery) that provides a `domready` event
  - Run the script in a `<script>` directly (instead of assigning an event handler)

Answer (score 4):

`OnLoad` waits for all images and other external resources to be completely loaded. If you only want to know that the entire DOM tree with all HTML elements have been loaded, use `OnDOMReady`.

Note that this is not a trivial task if you want it to work well across many browsers. If you're using jQuery, then they've solved the problem for you, and you can write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Mine();
});
```

But if not, loading jQuery only for that feature might not improve your page load at all. Another solution, then, would be to put the call just before `</body>`:

```
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">Mine();</script>
</body>
```

Most of your DOM tree should be available to you at that point, so that might be a way to go.

Comment: I use JQuery approach very often. If you do not know JQuery, it definitively worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious answer: Speed up your page load.

onLoad means, that function will be run after your whole page has finished loading.

Comment: Downvote! Ouch. Sorry, after reading it again, it does sound condescending. Didn't mean to.

Comment: CAn anyone explain in simpler terms ?